# While writing selenium code with python for microsoft edge, why i am getting this error?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver=webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"C:\Users\KAUSTUBH\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
print(driver.title)
```

*why i am getting this error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find MSEdge binary ?*

```
    **i have downloaded this  81.0.409.0 browser driver of microsoft edge**
```

Comment: Have you done "from selenium import webdriver" first?

Comment: Yes i have added that and edited my code. @deefunkt

Comment: This question has been asked before, have you tried the answers there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169524/using-python-selenium-for-microsoft-edge

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\msedge.exe'
driver = Edge(executable_path=r'c:\Bin\webdriver\msedgedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://youtube.com/')
```